# Is there a way to divide notepad++ into pages

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++

I'm writing some info for studying that i'm doing and I wanted to divide the info into pages (i'm using notepad++ because I got java code in it).

I want something like word (Microsoft office word), that I can divide it into pages and make it more organized.

until now I did something like that

```
-------------------
infoinfo
infoinfo
infoinfo
-------------------
moreinfo more info
moreinfo more info
moreinfo more info
moreinfo more info
-------------------
moreinfo more info
moreinfo more info
moreinfo more info
-------------------
```

anyone have solution for me?

Comment: For printing you meant?

Comment: Short answer: No. notepad++ is a text editor not a word process. It doesn't know about pages.

Comment: Well yes notepad++ is an editor, but an editor can write anything even [markdown so I'd google for it](http://www.google.com/search?q=notepad%2B%2B+markdown)